# Trying to get property of non-object “ wordpress ”

Tags: php, oop

My WP theme got these notice on description menu function

my code :

http://www49.zippyshare.com/v/89513423/file.html

```
/* Discription Navigation Menu, Credit to Christian Kriesi  */

class description_walker extends Walker_Nav_Menu

{

      function start_el(&$output, $item, $depth, $args)
      {
           global $wp_query;
           $indent = ( $depth ) ? str_repeat( "\t", $depth ) : '';

           $class_names = $value = '';

           $classes = empty( $item->classes ) ? array() : (array) $item->classes;

           $class_names = join( ' ', apply_filters( 'nav_menu_css_class', array_filter( $classes ), $item ) );
           $class_names = ' class="'. esc_attr( $class_names ) . '"';

           $output .= $indent . '<li id="menu-item-'. $item->ID . '"' . $value . $class_names .'>';

           $attributes  = ! empty( $item->attr_title ) ? ' title="'  . esc_attr( $item->attr_title ) .'"' : '';
           $attributes .= ! empty( $item->target )     ? ' target="' . esc_attr( $item->target     ) .'"' : '';
           $attributes .= ! empty( $item->xfn )        ? ' rel="'    . esc_attr( $item->xfn        ) .'"' : '';
           $attributes .= ! empty( $item->url )        ? ' href="'   . esc_attr( $item->url        ) .'"' : '';

           $prepend = '<span>';
           $append = '</span>';
           $description  = ! empty( $item->description ) ? '<span class="nav-sec">'.esc_attr( $item->description ).'</span>' : '';

           if($depth != 0)
           {
                $description = $append = $prepend = "";
           }

            $item_output = $args->before;
            $item_output .= '<a'. $attributes .'>';
            $item_output .= $args->link_before .$prepend.apply_filters( 'the_title', $item->title, $item->ID ).$append;
            $item_output .= $description.$args->link_after;
            $item_output .= '</a>';
            $item_output .= $args->after;

            $output .= apply_filters( 'walker_nav_menu_start_el', $item_output, $item, $depth, $args );
            }
}
```

my wp_nav_menu :

```
  $header_menu_args = array(    
      'theme_location' => 'main_menu',                                
      'container_class' => 'menu',
      'container_id' => 'dropdown',
      'menu_id' => '', 
      'menu_class' => 'sf-menu',
      'echo' => true,
      'before' => '',
      'after' => '',
      'link_before' => '',
      'link_after' => '',
      'depth' => 0,
      'walker' => new description_walker()                                
  );
  wp_nav_menu( $header_menu_args );
  dropdown_menu( $header_menu_args );
```

the problem is in the line 44, 46, 47, 49 for the property of non object.

http://multipixels.net/files/theme_function_debug.png

please help me to figure it out please.

Best regards,
Decneo

Comment: `dropdown_menu()` is not a valid function.

Comment: so I have remove dropdown_menu() ? the issue is $args

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the `$args` passed to the function is not an object for some reason. I can't see the origin of this problem but for a quick solution, you can add `$args = (object) $args;` before the first time you use `$args`, here on line 44

Also, as commented by toscho, `dropdown_menu()` is not a valid function in wordpress core

Comment: so I have to put $args = (object) $args; before $item_output = $args->before; ...  right? and remove  dropdown_menu( $header_menu_args ); line?

Comment: that's correct.

Comment: Thank you Mridul Aggarwal, I will do that like you said then will tell you what's happen, because on my side I didn't get this notices after using debug bar plugin. only on my reviewer side got this.so I have to sent the theme file to the reviewer and waiting for his response.

Comment: How can I do Mridul Aggarwal if the notice still show.

Comment: I think the notice might be due to some other code

Comment: Thanks you Mridul Aggarwal your code it fix this issue,I just clear the database and the notice gone now with your code. thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

For those looking for the answer to this problem it is a bug and has been reported to the core trac.

The problem is being caused by a nav menu item. This item needs to be removed. Save your menu and the notice will go away.

Personally I rebuilt my entire menu.